# Is using the if then symbol okay to use in regular proofs, and at what point is using symbols too much only to be reserved for set-theory?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

In calculus, we are proving statements since the course is a proof-based course. One such proof is the proof that $|ab|=|a||b|$. The proof makes sense but seems like it ought to be seen in set-theory, not calculus. The final statement is $\therefore\forall$ $ a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ $|ab|=|a||b|$. While this makes sense, is this okay for a calculus proof? Also, on another proof about absolute value, I would like to write $\therefore a\le k \rightarrow|a|\le k$. This would mean "therefore if/since $a\le k$, then $|a|\le k$". Is this a "proper" use of $\rightarrow$? In other words, does this fit within the scale of calculus or should it be kept to set-theory? Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: What you wrote isn't correct.  Did you mean $\forall a, b \in \Bbb R~\vert ab \vert = \vert a \vert \cdot \vert b \vert$?

Comment: Deleted my last comment since I think I was being too soft.  As a matter of principle I would try to avoid using symbols from mathematical logic in prose outside of the symbolic definition of a mathematical object.  In other words, write out "for all" in the sentence "For all $x, y\in \mathbb R$, we have $x^2+y^2\geq 0 $ ", but you can still write $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2\leq t^2\text{, } \forall t\in T\}$.

Comment: @RobertShore thanks that's what I meant. I'll edit it.

Comment: @MW Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: @MW Could you also answer whether or not it makes sense within context rather than if you personally would use it here?

Comment: @WesleyBoudreau I hope the posted answer was along the lines of what you're looking for, if not let me know.

Comment: My recommendation: write the logic in words, not symbols.  Except when time is limited (e.g. writing live on a blackboard or an in-person written exam), or when space is limited (e.g. a box in a table).  Otherwise, please write everything out in words.

Comment: Writing "$\therefore a\le k \rightarrow|a|\le k$" does not save much space over "thus $a\le k$, so  $|a|\le k$".

Comment: Sorry for beating a dead horse, but I came here to say that it hurts readability and aesthetic beauty when these symbols are sprinkled needlessly into proofs, and I, as well as every professor I respected through my PhD, enjoined students to write in proper prose, for good reason.  Logical implication arrows have no place in a prose proof, and in fact are an outright shiboleth in academic mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading my comment to an answer.

As a matter of principle I recommend trying to avoid using symbols from mathematical logic in prose outside of the symbolic definition of a mathematical object. This is because it can make your proofs overly terse.

In other words, write out "for all" in the sentence "For all $x,y\in\mathbb R$, we have $x^2+y^2\geq 0$.", but you can still write $$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2\leq t^2\text{, } \forall t\in T\}\text{.}$$

However, I will add that it is not logically incorrect to use symbols in a proof, as long as the meaning is understood by the reader.  That is a key consideration, as all writing, even proof-writing, is an exercise in communication.

To your next point, on the proper use of "$\rightarrow$" in the statement "$\therefore a\le k \rightarrow|a|\le k$", this symbol is often used for convergence, so in this context, if you really must use a symbol for implication, better to use a double arrow, e.g. $\implies$.

[Edit: note that as for the actual mathematics, I'm sure you're aware that in a vacuum, $a\le k \implies |a|\le k$ is a false statement, as in the case $a=-5, k=2$, for example.]

Comment: Thank you so much! In regards to the actual mathematics, I did not write out all the steps of my proof, only the one I was wondering about so the statement is indeed false. To add context, I let $a \ge 0$ and was given that $-k \le a \le k$.